# Slope of a curve at origin

Tags: derivatives

Suppose there is a general curve f(x,y)=0.We need to find the equation of tangent at origin....Suppose I wish to use the trivial method....i find the derivative of the given function using implicit differentiation... Naturally or supposedly the derivative comes as a function of x and y.... Now to find the slope at origin I plug in x=0 and y=0 in the obtained derivative....but the derivative takes the form 0/0.... So now how to proceed forward to find the slope at origin....even if I use the concept of multivariable limit and use l'hopital rule I will obtain only a single value of limit but for almost all the curves there are 2 equations of tangent suggesting two slopes...and if I am going wright can there be an error in finding the limit....or is there another way of finding the slope at origin using derivatives.....i don't want to use any other method....and if my method is wrong then what's the fault in it

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is not applicable for multivariable limits. Perhaps if edit your post to include the limit in question, someone can further assist you.

Comment: It would help to discuss your problem in terms of a specific example. Also, the concept of derivative is valid for 'functions' and not for 'relations' (where a single x value has more than 1 y value).

Comment: A good example would be x^3 + y^3 = 3axy....how to find the slope of this curve at origin

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example of such a function.

Consider $y^2=2x^2(1-x^2)$ or $y^2=2x^2-2x^4$

By implicit differentiation $2y \frac {dy}{dx}=4x-8x^3$

$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-4x^3}y$

This would have the problem described by the OP - at $(0,0)$ the curve crosses itself, meaning that there are two different tangents depending n which bit of the curve you are concerned with.

In this case it is possible to replace "$y$" in the denominator with "$\sqrt{2x^2-2x^4}$" There are two possibilities for the square root, giving two expressions (in terms of $x$, so l'Hopital can be used):

$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-4x^3}{\sqrt{2x^2-2x^4}}$

$\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x-4x^3}{\sqrt{2x^2-2x^4}}$

In this case there is no problem at all if the curve is written in parametric form:

$x=\cos t$

$y=\sin 2t$

because the two times when the curve goes through the origin have two different values of $t$ and can thus be distinguished easily.

Comment: Can u help me on the question x^3 + y^3 = 3axy.....slope at origin?